# Highcharts Solid Gauge: Remove Wasted Space in Pane

Tags: highcharts

I am currently laying out a page that uses multiple charts and I can't seem to remove the wasted space from a Highcharts Solid Gauge. I am only using 50% of the chart from range -90 to 90 yet the pane size is for 100% of the arc drawn. How can I reuduce the wasted space?

**Current:**

[image: Before]

**Desired:**

[image: After]

I am using the following container:

```
<div id="container-ping" style="height: 20vh; width: 33.33%; float: left"></div>
```

These are the Solid Gauge parameters:

```
// Create the ping chart
$('#container-ping').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge'
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        stops: [
            [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
        lineWidth: null,
        tickLength: 0,
        tickPositions: [0, 500],
        minorTickLength: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickAmount: 2,
        title: {
            y: 0
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: true,
            distance: 15,
            align: 'center'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                y: 0,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
    },
    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '50%'],
        size: '100%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            borderColor: '#aaa',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: processedData[0]['name']
    },
    series: [{
        data: [processedData[0]['data'][0]],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:12px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>'
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Highcharts use the height of the container unless you specify the [height](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height) - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7rufzd4/)

Answer (score 1):

User ppotaczek mentioned a way to resize the chart using another function. This helped me look in the right direction in adding the height to the chart settings. This sizes the chart how I needed and did not require a redraw.

```
      chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge',
        height: (70) + '%',
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, you should use **height** option for the chart. Also, you can use **center** and **size** properties to optimize the space occupied by the chart.

```
pane: {
    center: ['50%', '85%'],
    size: '140%',
    startAngle: -90,
    endAngle: 90
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eo47dyam/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/pane.center

Comment: I have gone through these settings and I can manipulate the chart to look correct on a PC/browser but when it transfers to a mobile device, it does not scale in a pleasant manner. Maybe this is more HTML related than Highcharts related.

Comment: Hi kinser86, I think in this case the problem is related with Highcharts. You can try to change the height of the chart, depending on plotSizeX, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qfk3ouap/

Comment: I took what you suggested and removed the function to simply change the size and it is working as I wanted.